# google-maps-react disabling scrollwheel

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-react

is there a way to disable the scroll wheel? I'm not sure how to integrate this option into google-maps-react.

I tried this:

```
defaultOptions={{
    scrollwheel: false,
  }}
```

and this:

```
MAP_OPTIONS = {
  scrollwheel: false,
}
```

but it doesn't work for me

It would be awesome if you could help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the code for your entire GoogleMap component?

Comment: https://codepen.io/Olga_P-S/pen/zEYbBQ

Comment: And you have tried `<Map defaultOptions={{scrollwheel: false}} ` ?

Comment: Yes and it doesn't work for me :/

Answer (score 0):

In https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react you have the chance to add the options as element properties.

According to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction you can remove the scroll wheel by disabling "pan interactions" (**gestureHandling: 'none'**)

solution:

```
<Map
  zoom={12}
  initialCenter={{ lat:-34.5920552, lng: -58.4253941 }}
  streetViewControl={false}
  fullscreenControl={false}
  gestureHandling='none' //this will disable scroll wheel
>
</Map>
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you provide the entire code please ?

Did you place it in the GoogleMap tag ?

```
<GoogleMap
  defaultOptions={{
    scrollwheel: false,
  }}
/>
```

It should work like this.
Have a nice day,